# How to designate if some DateTime value is in the same day in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

For example there will be some event today at 20:30. We sold the tickets earlier that day. The tickets can be returned only in the same day.

Somebody wants to return the ticket today it doesn't matter if it's before or after event time, but it should be in that day.

How to designate if some DateTime value is in the same day in C#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

Comment: What code have you tried? Please show us so we can help.

Comment: Do you need to take into account tickets sold across multiple time zones as being within that `day` window?

Comment: It's in the same time zone for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN docu of DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2013, 6, 27, 7, 47, 0);
// Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;

if (Date1.Date == Date2.Date)
{ //lucky Day}
else 
{ // loser
 }
```

But if your building a new tool.
Use **DateTimeOffSet**

See the Now and Today properties

Comment: What does it mean "But if your building a new tool. Use DateTimeOffSet"?

Comment: DateTime is inherently weak.Since you dont know the timezone it refers to.  If you have the chance only use DateTimeoffset.  That way you always know the time and you can display it in any timezone.  That way the Server can has a base/local time.  USers can have a local time and there is never an ambiguous interpretation. EVEN the DB, eg SQL can store DATETIMEOFFSET.

Comment: Oh By the way I notice, the tick magnet himself (c# time guru) has made a post.  Check out his NodaTime tool http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/  if you are serious about managing time in .net.

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
if (ticket.Date == now.Date) // For some value of now
```

Or perhaps:

```
if (ticket.Date == DateTime.Today)
```

? You need to consider whether time zones could cause you a problem, too... You need to be aware that [`DateTime` has some significant ambiguities](http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) - it's easy to avoid thinking about the things that you should really be paying attention to, particularly in terms of which time zone you're interested in.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you could indeed use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), at which point you'd want to compare `LocalDate` values - again, you still need to consider which time zone is relevant.

Comment: He could try the awesome new NodeTime library that I heard some smart guy wrote. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(yourEventDate == DateTime.Today)
```

will that work?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this(with the time of event checking added if by some case needed).

```
if ((DateVariable.Date == DateTime.Today) && (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(20,30,0))) 
{
    //your work here....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to compare the properties of each `DateTime`.

For instance:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01, 01, 00, 00); // Jan 1th, 2013 - 01:00 AM
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01, 02, 00, 00); // Jan 1th, 2013 - 02:00 AM

if (date1.Day == date2.Day && date1.Month == date2.Month && date1.Year == date2.Year)
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: Comparing only a day could be last month, last year, etc.  This should be more specific.

Comment: Jan 1st 2013 and May 1st 1647 are not the same day